# Django substract symbols from path

Tags: django

I'm looking fow way to substract few sybmols (file extention).
This construction {{ post.path }} retuns link `abc/def.html`
I need to remove `.html` to have a link looks like "abc/def/".

Comment: Is `post` an instance of your models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can write a method in your model which will return the `path` without extension.

```
import os.path

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # ... fields ...

    def get_path(self):
        # split the extension
        path, ext = os.path.splitext(self.path)
        # append a slash
        path += '/'
        return path
```

And in your templates, access it by `{{ post.get_path }}`